# Upgrade single dropdown calculator to multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got this script:

Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EfYev/4/

At this moment it works only for the first field. It goes like:
Number in text field*span value of dropdown=result in other currencies
How can make rearrange the script to make it work with multiple dropdowns, so it will work like
(number*span value)+(number*span value) and show it as one result?(summed up)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showTab(name) {
        $('div.fruit').hide();
        var $div = $('#' + name).show();
        var number = parseInt($('.number').val(), 0);
        $('span', $div).each(function () {
          $(this).text(($(this).data('val') * number).toFixed(3));
        });
    }

    $('#update').click(function() { 
        showTab($('#dropdown').val());
    });

    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```

Comment: Duplicate ids.... Change it to className and bind event on to that.

Comment: Change your #update id to a class since you're using two buttons with the same ID

Comment: Fiddle updated. Changing classes still is just a starter. Any advices on next steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright first off this is in no way the best way to do this. I took a lot of liberties with the answer and hard coded the values.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/EfYev/7/)**

I cleaned up the html a little bit, but mainly only made changes to the JavaScript.

First thing I did was like I said hard code the values.

```
var fruits = {
    apple: {
        apple: 1,
        banana: 0.5,
        pineapple: 8
    },
    banana: {
        apple: 2,
        banana: 1,
        pineapple: 16
    },
    pineapple: {
        apple: 0.125,
        banana: 0.0625,
        pineapple: 1
    }
};
```

Now personally I would make your HTML easier to read and iterate via JS to create the object dynamically. That is of course if you are expecting different values from the server and the *only* way to get them for some reason is via the HTML data attributes.

The next thing I did was change your click event to the following.

```
   var vals = {
        apple: 0,
        banana: 0,
        pineapple: 0
    };

    $('.dropdown').each(function () {
        var fruitVal = $(this).prev('.number').val();
        if (fruits[$(this).val()]) {
            vals.apple += fruitVal * fruits[$(this).val()].apple;
            vals.banana += fruitVal * fruits[$(this).val()].banana;
            vals.pineapple += fruitVal * fruits[$(this).val()].pineapple;
        }
    });

    $('.apple').text(vals.apple);
    $('.banana').text(vals.banana);
    $('.pineapple').text(vals.pineapple);
```

Again I would have dynamically made the `vals` object based on the data received earlier. I would have iterated the top properties from the fruits object to create it.

In my opinion its weird to have two calculate buttons. Also I *hate* using prev to get a value, but you had no class assigned to the inputs so basically no way to reference what input belonged to what drop down.

Anyway once you get the values it just comes down to basic math. If you have any questions feel free to ask.